# Gradle build comes up with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, junit5, java-11

In a project I am using gradle, Java11, SpringBoot, Junit5. The application is launching without any problem and when I run the unit tests individually everything is fine.
However, when I run gradle->build task the following error appears:

```
Task :test FAILED
JwtTokenProviderTest > initializationError FAILED
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
1 test completed, 1 failed
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
```

More ever, I tried the following config in build.gradle

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
  scanForTestClasses = false
  include "**/*Test.class" // whatever Ant pattern matches your test class files
}
```

But it does not fix the problem.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Possibly compatibility issues?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Maybe, but I could not find the root cause.

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using and do you have the current version of JUnit 5 and its dependencies specified. Also do you have the `useJUnitPlatform()` set in Gradle config?

Comment: @cjstehno the only thing that is different I am not using useJUnitPlatform() in test, let me check it.